# Cloud Functions for Firebase HelloWorld "Error: An unexpected error has occurred."

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When trying to run the simple HelloWorld Example found on [firebase youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ).

Im further confused as it does not provide an detailed error message and log files found with command `firebase functions:log` is empty.

I am also using Webstorm as my IDE

Here is a screenshot of the terminal
[image]

index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: The deployment failed, so nothing will be logged on the server yet. Check the `firebase-debug.log` file to see if it contains anything helpful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen checked within root directory and functions folder there is no firebase-debug.log file.

Comment: Try running `firebase deploy --debug`

Comment: thats command produced an error message and i was able to solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the `Node` with version `8.0.0`.
Just downgrade it.

I've tried with `6.10.3` and got success :)

Comment: the issue was actually the opposite, I was running an older version of node. I had to upgrade

Comment: So you were using the node with lower version than `v6.10.3` :)